# Sending post request to API with multipart content-type

Tags: api, postman, multipartform-data, multipart, charles-proxy

I am trying to send a post request though an api. The call requires:

```
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=[boundary_number]
```

I have used Charles HTTP proxy to watch see what headers/content I need to send.

[image: charles]

**My Request: (basically copied from Charles' multipart section)**

```
--324a08fa-6b58-424a-a1ad-691123d9d04b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message[body]"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 5

Text!
--324a08fa-6b58-424a-a1ad-691123d9d04b--
```

[image: postman]

** My Headers:** 
[image: headers]

**My Result:**

When I post this in postman, the response just displays 'Loading'

I can't seem to satisfy the content I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The response is not as expected because the `Content-Length` of HTTP request body is incorrect. It should be `240`, not `238`.

For HTTP request in Charles screenshot, the `message[body]` data is `qqq`, which is also indicated by `Content-Length: 3`. However, in your HTTP request in postman, the `message[body]` data is `Text!`. While its own `Content-length` is correct (`5`), the `Content-length` of the whole request body is not changed accordingly -- it's still `238`, which should be increased to `240`.